# Cannot tftp from DLINK 600M router to upgrade Firmware

Tags: router, firmware, tftp

I have tried upgrading firmware through wireless. I think it went fine I assume, as I can access my router through the web interface.

But now, I cannot connect to the internet, IP and DNS Server are at 0.0.0.0. I have called the Manufacturer Customer care for their help, but it did not resolve anything.

Then I tried to revert back to my original firmware version, but strangely I could not find the corresponding tab. There is nothing under Maintainence -> and even stranger there is no Tools tab.

I have tried to do an emergency flash, but no matter how many times I try, I never get to the page where I have to upload a firmware file.

**Update 1**

I am able to connect to router through telnet, how can I change my firmware through telnet.

I found these are the list of commands on my router

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I have done the following, but there is no result

```
1. I have connected to my router through telnet
2. Setup TFTP Server on local subnet (192.168.0.2)
3. I have tried to use tftp client on router to dump the firmware but always face timeout
```

I have disabled firewall and window defender and even created a rule in inbound rules in firewall settings, but still face timeout.

**Screen Shot of TFTP Server Log **

[image]

Comment: that's why updating on wireless is a bad idea.  try telnet

Comment: can you provide a guide?

Comment: if DLink support cannot fix, it's no good.

Comment: they have asked me to contact broadband provider and get mac address released. which I did not understand

Comment: cable ISP's lock modem/router machine address (MAC) so no login is required and your WAN IP address is constant. Can you see menu item to clone MAC from PC to router? I don't believe that will fix router menu , but call ISP.  Can you connect PC direct to modem?

Comment: yes I can connect PC to modem using ethernet cable

Comment: can you record IP, DNS, gateway and setup manually?

Comment: yes I can do, DLINK support guided me through that

Comment: then clone MAC address